# pecl: command not found

Tags: model-view-controller, phalcon, pear, pecl

Im trying to install Phalcon on my mac with Pecl. When I use any pecl command (for example: pecl channel-update pecl.php.net  I get the error: Pecl: command not found. I have installed pear and to my knowledge pecl comes with pear. I know pear works because when I type Pear version I get the following: PHP Version: 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS)
Zend Engine Version: 3.3.24

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Find out where `pear` is: `which pear`. Then look in the same folder, it should contain the `pecl` script.

If it does not exist, copy the `pear` script to `pecl` and adjust the last line by replacing `pearcmd.php` with `peclcmd.php`.